# Casteljau's algorithm - practical example

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, math

I have a dataset with about 50 points (x,y) and I would like to draw a smooth curve that can pass as closer as possible on those points.

I have heard about Casteljau's algorithm for splines but after hours searching on google I was not able to find a single piece of code I can use.

As far as I understood, to use this algorithm, I have to divide my dataset in groups of 4 points, right? 1234 5678 etc.. and as far as I noticed, my only problem is to find the points in the middle of each group. I mean, if I am calculating a curve for points 1234, I already have points 1 and 4 and I need to calculate 2 and 3, right? But it is a mystery to me how to do that.

I would like to ask you guys if you know some code in C, C++ or Objective-C that computes the curves based on datasets with any amount of number.

What I need is: I send the code an array with the dataset and I receive back an array with the points to draw.

**My math is rusty. So, please give me practical examples. Do not send me to pages with math theory and equations. Looking at these pages makes my brain hurt...**

Just tell me what to do with the points I have to compute the bezier.

**Answer as you would ask a 10 year old child... :D**

thanks.

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to build a Bezier using de Casteljau's algorithm!  The result for 50 points is a degree 49 polynomial, and you don't want to evaluate that monster.  Furthermore, it isn't an interpolating method--you're only guaranteed to pass through the first and last point.  What you really want is to interpolate a b-spline, which is is made up of a sequence of low degree polynomials with degree-1 continuity between the pieces.  Unfortunately you'll have to put a little effort into this, but maybe you can find a free libaray.

Comment: as far as I read, it divides the data sets in groups of 3 or 4 points and then calculates... but I may be wrong...if you can show me a code I am open to switch to b-spline :D

Comment: You have two problems: how to turn a collection of points into Bezier curves, and how to plot the curves. De Casteljau's algorithm only involves the second part of the problem, and may not even be the best method.

Comment: You can take a look at my youtube video on de Casteljau to get a better feel for what it's about.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YATikPP2q70.  You might have to work a bit to get the b-splines going.  It looks like there are a few opensource projects, including "libnurbs".  (Nurbs are a generalization of b-splines).

Comment: @DeepYellow - I have watched your video before. I understand it completely, great video. My problem is still converting that to code. As I said, I am searching for hours and found nothing practical, just theory. I need some lines of code to make my brain happy.

Comment: @Digital:  Understood.  Foovanadil posted some in his answer, which looks about right to me.  The best I could offer is some Mathematica code, if you want that.

Comment: as I said before, I am open to switch to any method that you guys can suggest, but you have to show me the code... :D

Comment: @Deep - thanks, but I don't have mathematica. Can you tell me in pseudo code what to do? for example... calculate this, calculate that, in simple steps? thanks. Fiivanadil code is crashing for me... :(

Comment: There's a nice treatment in c# at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx, but you're going to need some math and/or c# insight to translate it (translating it for you is too much to ask here).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about in C#?

```
private void drawCasteljau(List<point> points) {
            Point tmp;
            for (double t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.001) { 
                tmp = getCasteljauPoint(points.Count-1, 0, t);
                image.SetPixel(tmp.X, tmp.Y, color);
            }
        }


    private Point getCasteljauPoint(int r, int i, double t) { 
        if(r == 0) return points[i];

        Point p1 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i, t);
        Point p2 = getCasteljauPoint(r - 1, i + 1, t);

        return new Point((int) ((1 - t) * p1.X + t * p2.X), (int) ((1 - t) * p1.Y + t * p2.Y));
    }
```

From Here:

http://protein.ektf.hu/book/export/html/51

Comment: thanks, but wait a second, what is exactly this line "return points[i];" returning????

Comment: return points[i] returns the point value at index i. So if i == 5 then points[5] will return the point in the array that is at index 5. Hopefully that makes sense. In the context of this method it means. If r is 0 then just return the point as is without doing the calculation.

Comment: are you sure it is ok for a method to call itself? this will not end well... :(

Comment: recursion much? To further clarify, yes of course a method can call itself, it is called recursion. If you don't understand the concepts behind recursion you should read up on that before you will be able to do complex math in code.

Comment: yes I know recursion, but what I am saying is that the way it is done it is hanging... at least my translation to objective-c... it enters on an infinite loop and hangs.

Comment: I agree with Foovanadil, you have to understand recursion.  I wouldn't code this any different than he shows, although I usually compute a refinement as a piecewise linear curve, leaving it to some graphics abstraction to render it.  It does end well, just as soon as r==0!

Comment: As I said, I understand recursion but this code is still hanging.

Comment: You obviously made a mistake in your objective-c translation. It's easy to see that this recursion will end after r number of levels (or r-1 if you don't count the first call).

Comment: this line: if(r == 0) return points[i];  will stop the recursion so in your translation make sure you have something to this effect prior to the recursive calls.

Comment: I will accept the answer but it is unusable for what I want. I have discovered that my conversion is right. The problem is that the code is very slow. It takes 30 seconds to make one loop. With increments of 0.001 it will take 30,000 seconds (8 hours) to complete on the iPhone. So, for the iPhone the thread is technically hung and it kicks the app out, making it crash.

Comment: Fair enough. No need to accept the answer if it doesn't work for you.